# The multi-part identifier "" could not be bound. error on sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I write a query on sql server.
Here is tthe query..

```
 INSERT INTO #TEMPR(    
                            nQtyR ,
                            cBENoR ,
                            dBEDateR ,
                            nReceiveValueR ,
                            cRemarksR ,
                            nJobOrderDtlIdR ,
                            nSKUIdR ,
                            cSKUCodeR ,
                            cSKUDescriptionR,
                            nJobOrderIdR ,
                            cJobOrderNoR ,
                            nLocationIdR ,
                            LocCodeR,
                            nWtR ,
                            nVolR ,
                            cStatusR,
                            nASNIDR,
                            cPalletIDR )

                SELECT  SUM(WMS_InventoryTag.nCount) AS nQtyR, 
                    ISNULL(WMS_OutTurnDtl.cBENo,'') as cBENoR, 
                    WMS_OutTurnDtl.dBEDate as dBEDateR, 
                    isnull(WMS_OutTurnDtl.nReceiveValue,0) as nReceiveValueR, 
                    '' AS cRemarks, 
                    WMS_JobOrderDtl.nJobOrderDtlId as nJobOrderDtlIdR, 
                    WMS_SKUMst.nSKUId as nSKUIdR, 
                    WMS_SKUMst.cSKUCode as cSKUCodeR, 
                    WMS_SKUMst.cSKUDescription as cSKUDescriptionR,
                    WMS_JobOrder.nJobOrderId as nJobOrderIdR, 
                    WMS_JobOrder.cJobOrderNo as cJobOrderNoR,
                    WMS_LoactionMst.nLocationId as nLocationIdR,
                    WMS_LoactionMst.nLocationCode AS LocCodeR,
                    WMS_JobOrderDtl.nWt as nWtR,
                    WMS_JobOrderDtl.nVol as nVolR,
                    WMS_JobOrder.cStatus as cStatusR,
                    WMS_JobOrderDtl.nASNID as nASNIDR,
                    WMS_OutTurnDtl.cPalletID as cPalletIDR 
    FROM WMS_InventoryTrans inner JOIN WMS_OutTurnDtl ON WMS_OutTurnDtl.nOutTurnDtlId = WMS_InventoryTrans.nOutTurnDtlId 
                            INNER JOIN WMS_JobOrderDtl ON WMS_InventoryTrans.nJobOrderDtlId = WMS_JobOrderDtl.nJobOrderDtlId 
                            INNER JOIN WMS_SKUMst ON WMS_JobOrderDtl.nSKUId = WMS_SKUMst.nSKUId 
                            INNER JOIN WMS_JobOrder ON WMS_JobOrderDtl.nJobOrderId = WMS_JobOrder.nJobOrderId
                            INNER JOIN WMS_WarehouseMst ON WMS_WarehouseMst.nWarehouseId=WMS_JobOrder.nWarehouseId
                            INNER JOIN WMS_InventoryTag ON WMS_InventoryTrans.nInvTransId=WMS_InventoryTag.nInvTransId
                            INNER JOIN WMS_LoactionMst ON WMS_InventoryTag.nLocationId=WMS_LoactionMst.nLocationId
    WHERE WMS_JobOrder.cStatus='A' AND WMS_InventoryTag.cStatus='A' 
    AND 1=case when isnull(@JOBID,'')='' then 1 else case when WMS_JobOrder.nJobOrderId=@JOBID then 1 else 0 end end 
    and 1=case when isnull(@CUSTID,'')='' then 1 else case when WMS_JobOrder.nCustomer=@CUSTID then 1 else 0 end  end
    and 1=case when isnull(@locID,'')='' then 1 else case when WMS_LoactionMst.nLocationId=@locID then 1 else 0 end  end
    and 1=case when isnull(@asnID,'')='' then 1 else case when WMS_JobOrderDtl.nASNID=@asnID then 1 else 0 end  end
        and WMS_JobOrder.nWarehouseId=@WAREHOUSEID
    GROUP BY  WMS_OutTurnDtl.cBENo, WMS_OutTurnDtl.dBEDate, isnull(WMS_OutTurnDtl.nReceiveValue,0), 
              WMS_JobOrderDtl.nJobOrderDtlId, WMS_SKUMst.nSKUId, WMS_SKUMst.cSKUCode, WMS_SKUMst.cSKUDescription,
              WMS_JobOrder.nJobOrderId, WMS_JobOrder.cJobOrderNo,WMS_LoactionMst.nLocationId,WMS_LoactionMst.nLocationCode,WMS_JobOrder.cStatus,
              WMS_JobOrderDtl.nWt,
              WMS_JobOrderDtl.nVol,WMS_JobOrderDtl.nASNID,WMS_OutTurnDtl.cPalletID
    ORDER BY WMS_JobOrder.nJobOrderId
```

But when i Excecuting this query it returns the error messege

---

> The multi-part identifier "WMS_OutTurnDtl.cPalletID" could not be
>   bound.

I have idea what to do.

Comment: Check this table WMS_OutTurnDtl whether it is the right table or it contains the columns specified.

Comment: @Azar it have the column cPalletID

Comment: what abt remaining errors , solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the WMS_OutTurnDtl table. And check all columns are right